# Advantage of creating an Access-Violation for testing purposes with asm code?

Tags: delphi

We recently started using madExcept instead of ExcMagic as our Exception Handler.
We are also working on a 64 bit build of our app and therefore would like to eliminate, if possible, uses of asm code.

ExcMagic had this procedure to create an Access Violation for testing purposes.

```
procedure CreateAccessViolation
begin
  asm
    mov eax,11111111h
    mov ebx,22222222h
    mov ecx,33333333h
    mov edx,44444444h
    inc dword ptr [eax]
  end;
end;
```

Is there any advantage to using that code instead of just writing

```
raise EAccessViolation.Create('Just testing...');
```

There must be some reason the ExcMagic developers used that.

Thanks!

Comment: The original code produces an actual access violation error at the OS layer and lets it bubble up into the RTL to be converted to an EAccessViolation with a real EXCEPTION_RECORD assigned to it. Simply raising EAccessViolation manually is not the same thing, but for testing purposes it probably doesn't matter. A simpler way to cause a real AV is to write to invalid memory, such as through a nil pointer, and you don't need assembly code to do that, eg: `procedure CreateAccessViolation begin PInteger(nil)^ := 12345; end;`

Comment: @RudyVelthuis corrected. Thx!

Comment: First of all - that set of instructions is not guaranteed to create an access violation. It is not inconceivable that there are writable memory located at address $11111111. A NIL pointer write is always guaranteed to generate an access violation. That being said, this particular access violation is very easy to recognize as _the_ one that is created on purpose, so that may be the reason for this particular set of instructions.

Comment: That's a really bad way to produce an AV and as @HEARTWARE says might not even produce an AV but instead break your program in some other esoteric manner. The real question is why you feel the need to fake an AV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions, at the OS level, are not objects. They're numeric values that might carry additional context data. When you attempt to read or write an invalid address, you get exception code `Exception_Access_Violation` with context giving the attempted operation and address, but when you use the `raise` reserved word, you get exception code `cDelphiException` with connect giving a Delphi object reference. (Did you know you can throw *any* object, not just descendants of `Exception`?)

In Delphi parlance, an OS-level exception is referred to as a *run-time error*.

There's code in the SysUtils unit that will transform an access-violation run-time error, as created by your assembly code, into an `EAccessViolation` Delphi exception. That makes it easy to catch with Delphi's `try`-`except` syntax.

If there's non-Delphi code on the call stack (or maybe even Delphi code that isn't using SysUtils), it probably won't recognize the `cDelphiException` exception code, and even if it does, it might not be able to differentiate one Delphi object type from another. `Exception_Access_Violation`, on the other hand, is known throughout all Windows code.

If you want to test behavior from an access violation, it's probably best for there to be an actual violation of access. That's what the assembly code attempts to do. (Whether It succeeds at that is a separate issue.) If you want to test the catching of Delphi objects, then throw whatever objects you want, including instances of `EAccessViolation`.

Answer (score 3):

The access violation lists the address that was accessed (in this case `$11111111`).
Because its such an unusual address that would stick out.

If you look at a stack trace it usually lists the values of the registers at the time of the crash, because of their unusual values this is again a red flag.

My guess is that the codebase uses this to differentiate between its own exceptions and other exceptions by checking the magic numbers.

However this seems to me a very silly way of faking a custom exception.
A more informative approach would be to make your own class of exception and raise that.

```
type
  EMadException = class(Exception)
    //custom fields, constructors, properties, etc can be added
  end;

  begin
    raise EMadException.Create('info');
  end;
```

In the error dialog it will clearly state the name of the exception and any info you've provided.
This also makes it trivial to differentiate between your exceptions and everybody else's:

```
try
  DoSomething
except 
  on E: EMadException do ShowMessage('it''s mine');
  else ShowMessage('not mine');
end;
```